# Upload big image in chunks and create thumbnail - all on client side

Tags: php, javascript, upload, resize, thumbnails

Given a big image file say 15mb,
I would like to upload this file in chunks and also generate a thumbnail on client side (in memory) of the original image and also upload this to the server.

Most solutions suggest doing the thumbnail on the server side and I don't have that option due memory limitation on my hosting solution.

I have to do the processing on the client side.

Plupload is great but does not support this. A big mess to get it work because of the binding to file browser id.

uploadify seems promising but again it does only one thing at a time..

**So has anyone solved this?**

My JavaScript skills are not exactly at guru level any help is very much appreciated.   code, framework, jquery plugin etc..

platform info:
Server side is php (memory limit 48mb)
client, well the usual html, javascript, possibly flash only for this purpose.

Cheers!

Comment: You can't do taht in the client-side. JS can't access the file system yet, nor manipulate image files.

Comment: That's not what I'm saying. I'm saying given a image file send it to server side in chunks, and resize in memory and send it also as thumbnail to server.

Comment: Also regarding manipulation, once you have access to the image the actual manipulation is fully possible on the client (resize, crop or whatever) but saving it back on disk is not, for the reason you mentioned. See Plupload for ref.